# ln: failed to create hard link ‘/boot/initrd.img-3.6-trunk-rpi.dpkg-bak’ => ‘/boot/initrd.img-3.6-trunk-rpi’: Operation not permitted

Tags: raspbian, apt

```
pi@igla:~ $ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
pi@igla:~ $ uname -a
Linux igla.X.X 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
pi@igla:~ $
```

at the tail end of trying to `apt-get install sysdig`, I got following:

```
Setting up sysdig (0.1.89-1) ...
Setting up sysdig-dkms (0.1.89-1) ...
Loading new sysdig-0.1.89 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
It is likely that 4.1.19-v7+ belongs to a chroot's host
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u4) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.120+deb8u1) ...
ln: failed to create hard link ‘/boot/initrd.img-3.6-trunk-rpi.dpkg-bak’ => ‘/boot/initrd.img-3.6-trunk-rpi’: Operation not permitted
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.6-trunk-rpi
pi@igla:~ $
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

The actual `ln` error here is because the boot partition is FAT32 formatted.  This is required by the pi but also unusual in a linux context.  FAT filesystems do not permit [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) (or soft links).

The way the special pi kernel is packaged on Raspbian is distinct from the normal Debian practices.  Another difference is that, since it is built for a very specific piece of hardware, it does not use an [initrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd)/initramfs, which is a standard practice in the linux world beyond the pi.  So anything that depends on adding stuff to that won't work unless the install methodology is modified to accommodate.

Based on the output I would say this is a package that's simply in Raspbian because it has been transferred over from Debian's armel port.  Very likely no one has bothered checking it.  I am sure Raspbian lacks the people power to check everything (currently there are about **70,000 packages** in Debian stable).

To catch things like that they need to count on the community, and it appears you've found something that should be blacklisted/removed from the repos unless or until someone able and interested wants to customize the package appropriately (don't hold your breath).

You can file [a bug report here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/raspbian), but again keep in mind the "fix" will most likely be simply blacklisting the package.

I don't know anything about Sysdig beyond what I garnered glancing through their homepage, but since it seems geared toward monitoring containerized OS instances, and few if any people would be using containers on a pi, it makes sense this is something few if any people would have noticed before.